# bat file Creating new Bat file

Tags: batch-file

So, on school we need to make this assignment.
So we tried to make a bat file that make's some folders and dox.
but the problem is: we want to let the bat file make another bat file.(with commands in it)
but if we write it like:
echo. @echo off F: tree/f>menu.bat
this creates a .bat file that doesn't work. probebly cause we didnt add lines. so how to do this?
how do we fix this?

looking forward to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `>>` operator to add lines to existing files. One `>` by itself will create a new file (or overwrite the contents of an existing file).

```
echo @echo off >menu.bat
echo F: >>menu.bat
echo tree /f >>menu.bat
```